# What parameters does an array pass to a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am new to Javascript and I'm having a difficult time understanding what parameters an array passes to a function. I'll use the `sort()` method as an example. To sort numbers in ascending order you could have this:

```
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
points.sort(function(a, b){return b - a});
```

My question is what values are being passed from the array to the function, what does `a` and `b` represent.

Comment: They are elements from the array which `sort()` compares. You can answer questions like this for yourself by logging the values to the console within the callback function.

Comment: You can check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `a` and `b` are two elements that are compared. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Parameters)

> **compareFunction Optional**
>   Specifies a function that defines the sort order. If omitted, the array is sorted according to each character's Unicode code point value, according to the string conversion of each element.
>   **firstEl**
>   The first element for comparison.
>   **secondEl**
>   The second element for comparison

You can log the values inside function

```js
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
points.sort(function(a, b){
  console.log(a,b)
  return b - a
});
```